# Does Tor choose nodes from nearby countries to create circuits?

Tags: circuit

I am from a European country, and usually the circuits created by Tor include nearby European countries (although Tor sometimes chooses nodes from remote countries, but this is very rare). My question is: does Tor choose nodes from nearby countries by default?

I understand that maybe this is due to latency: if I am in a European country, and Tor always creates circuits like: Argentina - Azerbaijan - South Africa, the connection will probably go very slowly.

So, does Tor choose nodes from nearby countries by default?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No, Tor chooses nodes randomly. There are a lot of Tor nodes in Europe. So, you'll often see that your connections are using European nodes. (So does everybody else.)

Answer (score 1):

As [Greg Hewgill](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/1765/greg-hewgill) was saying: No, Tor chooses nodes randomly.
But you can change it easily.

1. Find where your torrc file is located.
2. Add a line like that `ExitNodes {**} StrictNodes 1`.
   Where `**` use needed specify needed country by entering its code in [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) format.

Also you could use this for entry nodes. Just simply replace `ExitNodes` with `EntryNodes`.
You could also enter nodes fingerprint in here (don't write it with curly brackets).
Separate different nodes using comma.

***P.S.*** Thank you, [Greg Hewgill](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/1765/greg-hewgill) to pointing out this for me.